# C# error when class shares name with namespace

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction, namespaces, language-design

**Assembly 1**

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Foo { }
}
```

**Assembly 2**

```
using Foo;

public class Bar 
{ 
    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
```

I discovered today that the above gives error `Type name expected but namespace name found`.

I find this surprising. As far as I'm aware, you can't declare a namespace variable, or new() a namespace. `Foo` is a type, and it's being used where the parser expects to find a type, so why can the parser not resolve it correctly? What language feature am I overlooking which means that the compiler team were unable to implement this?

Comment: see [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

Comment: I stepped on this also and had to use `using MyFoo=Foo;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Eric Lippert's blog posts (parts [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one); [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two); [three](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three); [four](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four)) give good insight into this. From part one:

> This reveals an interesting point about the design of the “type binding” algorithm in C#. That is, the algorithm which determines what type or namespace a name like “X.Y” is talking about. We do not “backtrack”. We do not say “well, suppose X means this. Then Y would have no meaning. Let’s backtrack; suppose X means this other thing, oh, yes, then Y has a meaning.” We figure out what X unambiguously means, and only then do we figure out what Y means. If X is ambiguous, we don’t check all the possibilities to see if any of them has a Y, we just give up.

Here we've only actually *got* an X, but I *think* the compiler tries to work out whether that means it's a namespace or a type *before checking whether or not there's anything else after it*.

Personally, I don't mind this restriction. It means you're discouraged from writing code with a namespace and class called the same thing - and as that's a confusing situation from a *human* point of view, I'm happy for it to be discouraged.

Comment: What about when you have a company name as the first part of the namespace? eg. a `MyProject` class in a `MyCompany.MyProject` namespace? This gets rid of the possible ambiguity, but would you still discourage it? (I do this a lot for the main static class of a project)

Comment: @ConnellWatkins: It doesn't get rid of the ambiguity if anything is written in the `MyCompany` namespace. I simply wouldn't do it, personally.